# Force div sizing to behave as img

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

My goal is to create a `div` element which sizing follows the sizing of an `img` in all situation.

I know the dimensions of the image: 300*200 pixels.

Simulate the scaling of the img when **img width is 100%**: WORKS

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-placeholder {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.image-placeholder-inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image-placeholder-inner img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;" class="simulate-container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="image-placeholder">

    <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
      <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width:400px;" class="simulate-container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="image-placeholder">

    <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
      <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simulate the scaling of the img when **img width is auto**: FAILS

Fails: The second blue rectangle should not be width 100%. `.image-placeholder` should have  `style="max-width:300px;"` to solve this.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.image-placeholder {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.image-placeholder-inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image-placeholder-inner img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;" class="simulate-container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="image-placeholder">

    <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
      <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width:400px;" class="simulate-container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="image-placeholder">

    <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
      <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image-placeholder" style="max-width:300px;">

    <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
      <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution to support width:auto and width: 100% is flexbox.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* width: auto; It does not matter in this example */
}

.image-placeholder {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.image-placeholder-inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image-placeholder-inner img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex simulate-container" style="width:200px;">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="image-placeholder">

    <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
      <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex simulate-container" style="width:400px; background: yellow;">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="image-placeholder">

    <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
      <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It might seem that the `div` sizing behaves as the `img`, but it is not. If we put this div into a grid or into a flex, the sizing will be different.

With **Flexbox**: FAILS
Fail: The first blue box does not scale down.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  justify-content: flex-start;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-placeholder {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.image-placeholder-inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image-placeholder-inner img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="simulate-container" style="width:200px;">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="flex-item">

        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">

        <div class="image-placeholder">

          <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
            <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="simulate-container" style="width:400px; background: yellow;">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="flex-item">

        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">

        <div class="image-placeholder">

          <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
            <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With **Grid**: FAILS
Fail: The blue box and the image has the same initial size. While the image scales down, the blue box still shows as full. They should have the same size over all three test.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-placeholder {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.image-placeholder-inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image-placeholder-inner img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="simulate-container" style="width:200px;">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-item">

        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">

        <div class="image-placeholder">

          <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
            <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="simulate-container" style="width:400px; background: yellow;">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-item">

        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">

        <div class="image-placeholder">

          <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
            <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="simulate-container" style="width:800px; background: yellow;">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-item">

        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">

        <div class="image-placeholder">

          <div class="image-placeholder-inner" style="width: 300px; padding-bottom:calc(200 / 300 * 100%);">
            <!--<img src="https://www.calliaweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/300x200.jpg" />-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is somehow related to the fact that the `div width:300px` has different meaning compared to an `img width:300px`. I want to mimic the `img` behaviour, but I'm stuck trying. Is it impossible or is there a different way to overcome this situation?

My other idea would be to use an SVG as it behaves as image does, but would be better to solve this with plain `div`.

Comment: Did you try <canvas>?

Comment: Not yet. I tried <svg />, but it has different behavior. What works the best right now is enconding an SVG image into img's src. <img class="svg" src="data:image/svg+xml;,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width=%22300%22%20height=%22200%22%20/%3E" alt=""/>

Comment: @user1039663 the canvas idea is great and seems to work like the the img with svg. <canvas width="300" height="200"></canvas> and it has far less code... :)

Comment: Maybe I should add an answer then.

Comment: Why not simply put an image in the div and set its visibility to hidden and it’s position to relative?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried canvas?

Other option is to use javascript combined with DOM change events and css width/height "px" properties or offset properties (offsetWidth and offsetHeight) to emulate it... but it will be heavy charge option, I only use js for more extreme cases.